# How do I load in JavaScript files if part of URL matched what's in my JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a JavaScript component. The aim is, if the part of the URL matches what's in my JSON then append these JavaScript files in the `<head>`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
         var obj = {
          "/category/woman/woman.htm": {
              file: "js/vendor/some1.js",
              file: "js/vendor/some2.js"
          },
          "/stormsites/fcuk/content/category/man.htm" : {
              file: "js/vendor/some3.js",
              file: "js/vendor/some4.js"
          }
        }

        for(var key in obj) {
          if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            var url = obj;
            if(window.location.href.indexOf(url) > -1) {

              // Need a for loop to create a script element for each obj.file
              var s = document.createElement("script");
              s.type = "text/javascript";
              s.src = obj.file;

              var n = s;
              $("head").append(n);  

            }
          }
        }
```

Any help is immensely appreciated, thanks

Comment: `var url = obj;`? Also, your objects are invalid. They have duplicate keys.

Comment: What is the problem / error?

Comment: @NitinDhomse The mechanism isn't working... I don't think it's checking the part url in the JSON in the if statement.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Its my first real attempt at using JSON in this way. How would I using JSON check whether the part URL is found, then load in these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your object (array instead of duplicate keys), and rewrote your logic. Main problem was that you were working off the object instead of the object's keys:

```
const obj = {
  "/category/woman/woman.htm": {
    files: ["js/vendor/some1.js", "js/vendor/some2.js"]
  },
  "/stormsites/fcuk/content/category/man.htm": {
    files: ["js/vendor/some3.js", "js/vendor/some4.js"]
  }
}

for (let url in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(url)) {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(url) >= 0) {
      for (let file of obj[url].files) {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = file;

        $("head").append(script);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... the only problem is that it's not getting the string of each file that needs to be loaded. Instead its returning the index.

Comment: Awesome! Worked a charm! Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If other things are working fine then try with a `contains()` function as follows.

```
if(window.location.href.contains(url)){
 // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: You mean `includes()`? In any case, both `contains()` and `includes()` have very bad browser support.